# Javascript Array duplicates and values

Tags: javascript

This is my first Stack Overlow question:

I got this array `[['a',12],['a',21],['b',1],['c',4],['c',5]]`

and I want to output it like this `[['a',33],['b',1],['c',9]]`

Anyone can give me an helping hand?

Comment: But the first array doesn't have `33` or `9` in it so how do you expect to output something from an array that doesn't exist..

Comment: Is the problem describing the steps needed to get that result, or is the problem coding those steps? And I'm assuming you want to sum all the numbers where the array has the same letter.

Comment: @NewToJS: It's clear that it's summing up the values of the second array entry in the sub arrays based on the first array entry matching.

Comment: I assume you want to add all the numbers which has the same letter. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Basic questions are not a problem, but you do need to make an effort to solve the problem, and *then* ask if you run into a specific issue doing so, showing what you've done so far. There are hundreds -- thousands -- of questions about how to do things with JavaScript arrays here on SO. Even if there isn't an exact duplicate (there probably is), those give you plenty to get started with.

Comment: I want to convert the first array to the second one, removing duplicates and summing the second elements.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Haha how did I not notice that! I should finish my morning coffee before opening stack overflow.

Comment: @Tholle I've tried to loop through the original array, get the first letter and first value and check if the next letter is the same, if so sum it otherwise move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash table for referencing the same result array with the same first item of the inner array.

The [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loops the array and looks if the string is already in the hash table. If not, then assign a copy of the inner array and push it to the result as well, then exit the callback.

If found, add the value of the inner array to the array of the hash table.

```js
var data = [['a', 12], ['a', 21], ['b', 1], ['c', 4], ['c', 5]],
    hash = Object.create(null), // generate object without prototypes
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!(a[0] in hash)) {
        hash[a[0]] = a.slice();
        result.push(hash[a[0]]);
        return;
    }
    hash[a[0]][1] += a[1];
});

console.log(result);
console.log(hash); // to show how it works
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You were a life saver!

Comment: @ogaitsinid Consider accepting and potentially upvote the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: @Tholle sorry for the delay, i went to lunch.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var data = [['a', 12], ['a', 21], ['b', 1], ['c', 4], ['c', 5]];

var result = data.reduce(function (a, b, i) {
    const c = a.filter(function (ax) { return ax[0] === b[0] });
    c.length > 0 ? c[0][1] = c[0][1] + b[1] : a.push(b);
    return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
// [[a, 33], [b, 1], [c, 9]]
```